# Will differentiation always give us the maxima and minima

Tags: calculus, derivatives

If a given a curve with a maxima and a minima will differentiation always give us the maxima and minima values ?

Is it possible that the curve will have the critical points and derivatives won't give us those values ?

Sorry if this seems to simple ,I am a newbie at calculus.

Edit : my question does not seem to be clear ," if a function has a maxima and minima will differentiation **ALWAYS** give us the critical points .

Comment: If the function is differentiable then at each of its critical points the derivative vanishes. In particular, the derivative vanishes at a local maxima/ local minima. However, the converse is not true: if the derivative vanishes at a point, it does not imply that the function has a local maxima/ local minima at that point.

Comment: There are three possible cases: Either the derivative is zero or undefined; or it's the end point of the domain; or it's at a discontinuity. So always go through these three options. For example, take $f(x) = |x|$. Clearly, there are no points where the derivative is zero, but somehow the minimum is at $x=0$ ... Can you see why?

Comment: If the derivative is zero, you are either at a maximum, a minimum, or a saddle point.

Comment: Additionally, a maximum or minimum could exist at the boundary of the domain, and the derivative is not guaranteed to be zero there at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an extract from [an educational source](https://www.whitman.edu/mathematics/calculus_online/section05.01.html) on this topic:

> Since the derivative is zero or undefined at both local maximum and local minimum points, we need a way to determine which, if either, actually occurs. The most elementary approach, but one that is often tedious or difficult, is to test directly whether the y coordinates "near" the potential maximum or minimum are above or below the y coordinate at the point of interest. Of course, there are too many points "near'' the point to test, but a little thought shows we need only test two provided we know that f is continuous (recall that this means that the graph of f has no jumps or gaps).

So apparently, one of the key points for being able to ascertain that the inflexion point(s) constitutes the existence of local maximum (minimum) points is based on a continuity assumption.

Note, one of this thread's questions is "Is it possible that the curve will have the critical points and derivatives won't give us those values ?" and there is nowhere use of the term "differentiable function".

Whereupon, [per Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differentiable_function#:%7E:text=In%20particular%2C%20any%20differentiable%20function,the%20location%20of%20the%20anomaly), to quote:

> In particular, any differentiable function must be continuous at every point in its domain. The converse does not hold: a continuous function need not be differentiable. For example, a function with a bend, cusp, or vertical tangent may be continuous, but fails to be differentiable at the location of the anomaly.

So, I would answer yes, as in the event the derivative cannot be computed at the anomaly (may not exist), one needs to inspect to the right and left of the curve (permissible per the continuity assumption) to determine the true nature of the inflexion point.

Answer (score 0):

The necessary condition for the existence of a local max or min at $x=a$ is that either $f'(a)$ does not exist or it it exists then $f'(a)=0$. Even if $f'(a)=0$ exists you may not get the explicit value of $a$.

For example $f(x)=x^4-x^3+2x+1 \implies f'(x)=4x^3-3x^2+2,$ but $4x^3+3x^2-1=0$ is not solvable by hand however its real root is at $x=-0.607007...$ which is obtainable numerically. In principle, $f(x)$ has one local min at $x=-0.607007...$

In books and in exams when you are asked to find max/min of $f(x)$, the Authors and Examiners see to it that $f'(x)=0$ is solvable by hand.

Answer (score 0):

Differentiation of a differentiable function $f$ always give you stationary points by looking for the points $x$ where $f'(x)=0$.

And amongst these will be inflexion points as well as local minimi and maxima and the global minimal or maximal; that is -  if it has them.